# NPM install -> but only add appropriate line to package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I have been wondering this for years, but never bothered to ask. There are many cases where I just want to add the appropriate line for the latest version of a package to `package.json`, without actually touching `node_modules`.

Say I want to add the latest version of lodash to my project w/o actually installing it to `node_modules`. Is there an NPM command to do that?

Let me know if there is a better way to phrase the question.

Comment: `vi package.json`?

Comment: right, but then you have to look up the latest version number of the package you want to install. that's not convenient at all right? in other words, this is easy "lodash":"latest", but that's not a good idea, so then we do `"lodash":"x.y.z"`, but we don't know what `x.y.z` is, only npm knows that, unless you want to do a fun websearch.

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone can think of something better, seems like a simple tool could be used to do this:

1. `npm view <pkg-name> version`
2. read package.json, add the dependency to dependencies, sort dependencies by name
3. save package.json

Comment: A function like `npmvp(){ version=$(npm view $1 version); echo "  \"$1\": \"$version\""; }` might help. `npmvp bluebird`  `"bluebird": "3.5.1"`

Comment: cool matt, yeah add that as your own answer and you will get an upvote at least

Comment: I agree that a bash function is better than an `npm install -g`, because I change global npm/node versions frequently, using nvm.

Comment: yeah if you just log it to the console, that's good enough, then you can manually change package.json, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

A simple sh function to fetch and format the data might help

```
npmvp(){
  npmvp_version=$(npm view $1 version)
  echo " \"$1\": \"$npmvp_version\""
}
```

[`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) might be another quick shell way

```
npmvp(){
  npmvp_name=$1
  npmvp_version=$(npm view $npmvp_name version)
  cat package.json | jq --arg name "$npmvp_name" --arg version "$npmvp_version" \
    '.dependencies[$name] = $version' > package.json.tmp
  #mv package.json.tmp package.json
}
```

Otherwise you could dig into the `npm` code and make something do the steps up to the actuall installation, rather than implementing something completely new yourself.